# How to prevent gcc preprocessor removing line continuation character?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Suppose there is a file(1.c) like this:

```
all: obj1 \
  obj2 \
  obj3
```

Process this file by gcc preprocessor, like this:

```
gcc -E 1.c
# 1 "1.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "1.c"
all: obj1
  obj2
  obj3
```

All the line continuation characters('\') have been removed.
Is there an option to keep line continuation characters in gcc?

Above file is not a valid C program, I only take it as an example. I meet a real similar case when I build Emacs 22.1: makefile in Emacs 22.1 is processed by C preprocessor.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04, gcc version is 4.8.2

I bypass this issue by replacing line continuation characters to a specify string, then restore it after preprocessor. I'm looking for a "graceful" solution.

Comment: Why such an old Emacs version?

Comment: Just for reading its source code.

Comment: have you tried two of them? `\\\`, it is very hard to show 2 the comment parser doesn't like it

Comment: The `imake` command used with X11 uses the C preprocessor to manage makefiles.  It uses a special notation with `@@` at the ends of lines to get around problems with the way the C preprocessor munges inputs.  Basically, the C preprocessor was designed for preprocessing C, not makefiles, and it behaves appropriately for C source code, not necessarily for makefiles.  Given that C is a free-form language and those backslashes appear outside string literals, there's no need in C for those backslashes.  Add a string split over two lines and the behaviour of the preprocessor is different.

Comment: @gradyplayer The special notation @@ is a valid continuation character in imake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe gcc's [traditional preprocessor mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-Mode.html) will work. Try `gcc -E -traditional`.

It will not quite do what you asked for; it will join the lines, so that:

```
all: obj1 \
  obj2 \
  obj3
```

becomes:

```
all: obj1 obj2 obj3
```

But that output is still a valid Makefile.

Traditional mode has [another advantage for Makefiles](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-lexical-analysis.html#Traditional-lexical-analysis):

> The form of horizontal whitespace in the input file is preserved in
>   the output.  In particular, hard tabs remain hard tabs.  This can be
>   useful if, for example, you are preprocessing a Makefile.

It's likely that the Makefile was designed for this mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can put another backslash on front of each one?
I'm not sure but it could solve your problem.

```
all: obj1 \\
  obj2 \\
  obj3
```

Comment: Might need to be three backslashes. The first escapes the second, and the third escapes the newline.

Comment: I don't want to modify the source, I'm looking for a graceful solution. Actually, I bypass this issue by replacing line continuation characters to a specify string, then restore it after preprocessor.